# Web server accessible by curl but not browser

Tags: go

I am trying to build a simple webserver in Go.  When started, however, the response (Hello, World!) is accessible via curl only.  Entering localhost:8080, 127.0.0.1:8080 or 0.0.0.0:8080 yields a refusal to connect (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED). Adding http:// in front of the address does not seem to change anything as the prefix disappears from the url bar before the loading attempt.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "net/http"
)

func ping(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("pong")) 
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/hi", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi")
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/ping", ping)

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
}
```

also, the output of netstat -tlnp is:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      4252/main
```

I have read some answers that say not to use TCP6 without giving the reason, but I do not even know how to stop that behavior.

So trying it again the next day, it works (as noted below).  Now, I am starting on the journey to understand why.  I will post again if I find a useful answer, but for now this is working code.  Thank you StackOverflow community!

Comment: For a start, try listening on `"127.0.0.1:8080"` instead—that'd be IPv4 local host, port 8080.

Comment: As to debugging a request made by a web browser, please try to re-do it with the "developer tools" console (typically opened by hitting `F12`) opened and its "Network" tab selected. See whether you see something offbeat happening—like using HTTPS instead of HTTP etc.

Comment: Sorry, I did not include all of the iterations that did not work.  I just retried 127.0.0.1:8080 as well as http://localhost:8080 to no avail.  When I look at Network, it shows that localhost failed.

Comment: i just test in chrome is all ok!!

Comment: I  test in chrome is all ok  too !!  I guess maybe it's the privacy policy settings on your browser.